# Pantheon- Files address bar content

Tags: pantheon-files

Latest versions in address bar displays file:///Dir1/Dir2.....
It is bit tricky to copy/paste in to terminal

Earlier versions (Freya) had just //Dir1/Dir2/.....

How to get around?

Regards,
Ivars

Answer (score 0):

There is an open PR about this (https://github.com/elementary/files/pull/1149) awaiting review and merging.  Should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, but meaning not in Hera ?

Comment: I meant in the next release of Files - which will be contained in a Hera software update at some point.